# map deep in collection

Tags: javascript, reduce, flatten

I need to get all "id" and "name" of a big collection I have. An array ob objects, that has array with objects (etc).

I can't get it to work without manually doing foreaches for as many levels there is, which is ugly.

I am using Lodash, so a solution using this would be lovely.

This is how the collection looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Living",
    "numberStories": 0,
    "subcategories": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Fashion",
          "numberStories": 0,
          "subcategories": {
            "data": [
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Accessories",
                "numberStories": 0,
                "subcategories": {
                  "data": [

                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Kid's Fashion",
                "numberStories": 0,
                "subcategories": {
                  "data": [

                  ]
                }
              }, (... etc)
```

So it needs to look in subcategories in each array of objects and collect id and name, so that I end up with all the ids names from all levels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use lodash for this purpose. A simple recursive function using `.reduce()` does the job for you

```
function flattenId(inArray){
 return inArray.reduce(function(output, elem){
   output.push(elem.id);
   return output.concat(flattenId(elem.subcategories.data));
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As above, this is probably easier to do with native javascript as it's recursive. This is the same idea as the previous answer, but using some cool features of ES6 (destructuring, rest params, arrow functions, default parameters), and it will save a reference to the parent id so you can rebuild the category tree if you need.

```js
const categories=[{id:1,name:"Living",numberStories:0,subcategories:{data:[{id:2,name:"Fashion",numberStories:0,subcategories:{data:[{id:3,name:"Accessories",numberStories:0,subcategories:{data:[]}},{id:4,name:"Kid's Fashion",numberStories:0,subcategories:{data:[]}}]}}]}}];

const flattenCategories = (categories, parent = null, ret = []) =>
  categories.reduce((acc, { id, name, subcategories: { data } }) =>
    acc.concat(
      { id, name, parent },
      ...flattenCategories(data, id)
    )
  , ret)


console.log(
  flattenCategories(categories)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Depending on your use case it might be overkill to use a library, but if so desired it can give you a lot more flexibility

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const categories = [{ id: 1, name: 'Living', numberStories: 0, subcategories: { data: [{ id: 2, name: 'Fashion', numberStories: 0, subcategories: { data: [{ id: 3, name: 'Accessories', numberStories: 0, subcategories: { data: [] } }, { id: 4, name: "Kid's Fashion", numberStories: 0, subcategories: { data: [] } }] } }] } }];

const r = objectScan(['**[*].id'], {
  filterFn: ({ context, value, parents }) => {
    context.push({
      id: value,
      name: parents[0].name,
      parent: parents.length > 2 ? parents[3].id : null
    });
  }
})(categories, []);

console.log(r);
// => [ { id: 4, name: "Kid's Fashion", parent: 2 }, { id: 3, name: 'Accessories', parent: 2 }, { id: 2, name: 'Fashion', parent: 1 }, { id: 1, name: 'Living', parent: null } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)